# debugfs does not stat filename with spaces

Tags: linux, filenames, ext

I'm using `debugfs` to stat a filename with spaces. The file exists, but I get this message (same message if I change spaces by `\` or write the filename between simple quotes):

```
$ sudo debugfs -R "stat /home/user/This is a test.txt" /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-lv_root
debugfs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
stat: Usage: stat <file>
```

If I use this format I get this error:

```
$ sudo debugfs -R "stat $'/home/user/This\x20is\x20a\x20test.txt'" /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-lv_root 
debugfs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
$'/home/user/This\x20is\x20a\x20test.txt': File not found by ext2_lookup
```

If I use this format I get this error:

```
$ sudo debugfs -R "stat $'/home/user/This\024is\024a\024test.txt'" /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-lv_root 
debugfs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
$'/home/user/This\024is\024a\024test.txt': File not found by ext2_lookup
```

Is it possible to stat a filename with spaces with `debugfs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stat` in `debugfs` expects exactly one argument (therefore `Usage: stat <file>`). The string you provided

```
/home/user/This is a test.txt
```

is seen as many arguments separated by spaces. The tool supports quoting with double quotes though. This will work:

```
sudo debugfs -R 'stat "/home/user/This is a test.txt"' /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-lv_root
```

Comment: Sorry, but I tink that I tested it before and does not work

    $ sudo debugfs -R 'stat "/home/user/This is a test.txt"' /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-lv_root 
    debugfs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
    /home/user/This is a test.txt: File not found by ext2_lookup

Comment: @oml Apparently there is no such file but the syntax is now correct. The response shows all spaces in the filename were recognized.

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I had a typo in the filename. You are rigth. It works fine now. Thanks a lot!